# Rails radio_button refactoring best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, radio-button

I'm actually using the form helper `radio_button` in my Rails project. When everything works fine, the code itself does not looks good to me :

**_form.html.haml**

```
#- Loop on durations types
- Product::DURATIONS.each_with_index do |name, index|
  #- If new record, then select the first index by default
  - unless @product.duration_type.present?
    - checked = (index == 0) ? true : false
  - else
    #- Otherwise, if edit, then select the product value
    - checked = (name == @product.duration_type) ? true : false
  = f.radio_button :duration_type, name, checked: checked
  = f.label :duration_type, name
```

**product.rb**

```
DURATIONS = %w( Hour Day Week Month Year )
```

Is there a better way to write this in a more DRY and Rails' like way?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is the Rail's way but it is a fun way and saves some lines.

The idea is to compare index of object's duration to current index in the loop. If `@product.duration_type` is not in `Product::DURATIONS`  or nil it returns `nil` which converted to integer by `to_i` gives 0 or the first radio button.

```
#- Loop on durations types
- Product::DURATIONS.each_with_index do |name, index|
  - checked = Product::DURATIONS.index(@product.duration_type).to_i == index
  = f.radio_button :duration_type, name, checked: checked
  = f.label :duration_type, name
```

Other option a bit more readable.

```
#- Loop on durations types
- Product::DURATIONS.each_with_index do |name, index|
  - checked = @product.duration_type ? (name == @product.duration_type) : (index == 0)
  = f.radio_button :duration_type, name, checked: checked
  = f.label :duration_type, name
```

Comment: changed the second method as there was a bug in it.